# Creating a div element inside a div element in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, createelement

I'm trying a very basic example of creating a `div` inside an already existing `div`.

It doesn't seem to be working when I use:

```
document.getElementbyId('lc').appendChild(element)
```

but works fine when I do this:

```
document.body.appendChild(element)
```

Do I need to add `windows.onload` function? Though it doesn't work even then!

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Enter your filter text here.." onkeyup = "test()" />

    <div id="lc">  
    </div>
</body>
```

JS code:

```
function test()
{
    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat'));
    document.getElementbyId('lc').appendChild(element);
    //document.body.appendChild(element);
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Your code works well you just mistyped this line of code:

<del>`document.getElementbyId('lc').appendChild(element);`</del>

change it with this: **(The "*B*" should be capitalized.)**

```
document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);
```

**HERE IS MY EXAMPLE:**

```html
<html>
<head>

<script>

function test() {

    var element = document.createElement("div");
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat'));
    document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);

}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<input id="filter" type="text" placeholder="Enter your filter text here.." onkeyup = "test()" />

<div id="lc" style="background: blue; height: 150px; width: 150px;
}" onclick="test();">  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's clearly a typo in the question. He said his code works fine.

Comment: I have added a working example so I think that I answered the whole question.

Comment: He said it works fine when he appends to body, not to the div

Comment: @MikeC: Oh yes, you're right. I'm going to add some formatting to that question. It's a mess.

Comment: It was because of the typo. Ugghhh really annoyed at myself

Answer (score 8):

'b' should be in capital letter in `document.getElementById`  modified code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5hzA/)

```
function test()
{

var element = document.createElement("div");
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode('The man who mistook his wife for a hat'));
document.getElementById('lc').appendChild(element);
 //document.body.appendChild(element);
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you either need to do this `onload` or in a `<script>` tag *after* the closing `</body>` tag, when the `lc` element is already found in the document's DOM tree.